# Nativescript/Angular - Bound tap function in template isn't found

Tags: typescript, nativescript, nativescript-angular

Trying to create an action bar with two clickable items which will lead to different routes but I can't seem to bind simple functions to the tap events.

Here's my template:

```
<ActionBar title="Map" icon="" class="action-bar">
  <ActionItem (tap)="goToTextMode()">
    <Button text="Text"></Button>
  </ActionItem>
  <ActionItem (tap)="goToSettings()" ios.position="right">
    <Button text="Settings"></Button>
  </ActionItem>
</ActionBar>
```

Inside component:

```
goToTextMode(): void {
  this.router.navigate(['text']);
}

goToSettings(): void {
  this.router.navigate(['settings']);
}
```

But when I tap on the "text" button I get this:

```
CONSOLE ERROR [native code]: ERROR TypeError: co.goToTextMode is not a function. (In 'co.goToTextMode()', 'co.goToTextMode' is undefined)
```

I'm baffled as to why this is happening, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can check app-module.ts file where you import all your components - is there correct URL for your component. I had the same error because there was an incorrect component url in module.ts.